# Github Actions: get stacktrace from a failed job

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, jira

I'm wondering if this is possible. I've done some googling, with various different wordings. I've been asked to add to a job that creates a jira ticket when a previous step fails (the previous step is a docker build command). At the moment the jira ticket has no description, and I've been asked to add something meaningful. I thought the stacktrace would be a good start - essentially what you see in Github when you navigate to the failed job. Is it possible to access this like a job output? Or does github provide it some way through the context or something like that?